# Log issue in Rails4 with Docker running rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rake-task

My rails4 application is running with docker. It runs a rake task for fetching messages from AWS SQS.

The problem I met is that **logs can't show up in a console in time**. The console doesn't show anything until exception/error comes. In other words, if my application works fine, no logs come to console. But if application went wrong, all the logs(info, warn and error) come together!

I already configure the **config/production.rb** as blow:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger.const_get('INFO')
config.log_level = :info
```

I google 'rake task log was not working', but nothing useful. Is this a rails log problem or a rake task log problem, or maybe a docker problem?

Hoping that get some advice!

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue where any rake task that I invoke doesn't output to STDOUT until the rake task has exited. I have tested this with the following code in a rake task: `loop { puts "in loop"; sleep 2 }`. While the task is running nothing appears in STDOUT, however once it completes both instances of "in loop" get output immediately. I haven't found why this is, but I'll post back here if I figure it out.

Answer (score 9):

Try disabling output buffering to STDOUT. You can do this by adding this line to your rake task:

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Note that I found this solution because `docker-compose logs -f <container>` was acting like it was buffered for me and I never saw the output.  So the problem was Ruby 1.9.3's output buffering (not sure if Ruby's default buffering has been fixed in later versions, but I prefer to always do everything synchronously like in PHP because determinism is generally more important than performance, at least during development).  More info at https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1549 and https://github.com/midori-rb/midori.rb/issues/150#issuecomment-359744382

Comment: Forgot to mention that the defaults are: `$stdin.sync`: false, `$stdout.sync`: false, `$stderr.sync`: true.  Although I'm not sure input buffering does anything.

Comment: This also works on Rails 3, and can be put inside `development.rb` (or your preferred configuration file for your environment)

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 4.x the log level is configuration

```
# Enable stdout logger
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

# Set log level
config.log_level = :ERROR
```

The logger level is set on the logger instance from config.log_level at:
(https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/railties/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb#L70)

Comment: Thanks, man! But I don't think this would fix my problem. The logs, including info, warning and error, wouldn't show up in time. They only come to the console when exception happends.

Comment: **ENV Configuration**

 # default :ERROR
  config.log_level = ENV.fetch("LOG_LEVEL", "ERROR")


**Run test from shell**

 # Log level :INFO (the value is uppercased in bootstrap.rb)
   $ LOG_LEVEL=info rake test

# Log level :ERROR
  $ LOG_LEVEL=debug rake test