# Logging to STDOUT in a ruby program (not working in Docker)

Tags: ruby, logging, docker, docker-compose

I'm dockerizing one of my ruby apps, but I've got this very strange logging behavior. It only seems to load when the program ENDS not while it's running. When I run the program (daemon) with `docker-compose` all I see is this:

```
Starting custom_daemon_1
Attaching to custom_daemon_1
```

However, if I put an `exit` part way into the program I see all my `puts` and `logger` outputs.

```
Starting custom_daemon_1
Attaching to custom_daemon_1
custom_daemon_1  | requires
custom_daemon_1  | starting logger
custom_daemon_1  | Starting loads
custom_daemon_1  | Hello base
custom_daemon_1  | Loaded track
custom_daemon_1  | Loaded geo
custom_daemon_1  | Loaded geo_all
custom_daemon_1  | Loaded unique
custom_daemon_1  | D, [2016-11-14T13:31:19.295785 #1] DEBUG -- : Starting custom_daemon...
custom_daemon_1  | D, [2016-11-14T13:31:19.295889 #1] DEBUG -- : Loading xx from disk...
custom_daemon_1 exited with code 0
```

The top ones without times were just `puts` debugging, seeing if it would show - the bottom two are created by:

```
Logger.new(STDOUT)
LOG = Logger.new(STDOUT)
LOG.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

Then I would call `LOG.debug "xxx"` or `LOG.error "xxx"` any idea why this strange behavior is happening? When I `ctrl+c` out of the first one, the logs still do not show up.

This was originally run by a `.sh` script and now I've made the call to run it directly as the `CMD` of the Dockerfile.

There is a python question I found asking something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379008/python-logger-in-docker-is-not-working). Someone speculates it may have to do with `PID 1` processes having logging to STDOUT surpressed.

**Test**

Here is a test I ran:

```
puts "starting logger"
Logger.new(STDOUT)
LOG = Logger.new(STDOUT)
LOG.level = Logger::DEBUG
puts "this is 'puts'"
p "this is 'p'"
LOG.debug "this is 'log.debug'"
puts "Starting loads"
```

outputs:

```
custom_daemon_1  | starting logger
custom_daemon_1  | this is 'puts'
custom_daemon_1  | "this is 'p'"
```

Notice that the first two `puts` printed but as soon as I try to use `LOG.debug` it didn't work.

**TEST 2**

I also decided to try the logger using a file, and as expected it logs to the file just fine, through docker.

All I did was change `Logger.new(STDOUT)` to `Logger.new('mylog.log')` and I can `tail -f mylog.log` and all the `LOG.debug` prompts show up.

Answer (score 10):

As say in this thread [Log issue in Rails4 with Docker running rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417888/log-issue-in-rails4-with-docker-running-rake-task)

Try disabling output buffering to STDOUT: `$stdout.sync = true`

Answer (score 0):

I've temporarily fixed this with adding a symlink to based on [this docker thread](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19616). In the Dockerfile:

`RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/mylog.log` and set my logger to, `LOG = Logger.new('/var/log/mylog.log')` but this has two undesired consequences. First, the log file will grow and take up space and probably need to be managed - I don't want to deal with that. Second, it seems inelegant to have to add a symlink to get logging to work properly... Would love another solution.